# Base class constructor being called but shouldn't be

Tags: java, constructor

I'm getting an error that says:

```
DerivedClass.java:6: error: constructor BaseClass in class BaseClass cannot be applied to given types;
    DerivedClass(String d) {
                           ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Here is my code:

```
class BaseClass {
    BaseClass(String f) {
       System.out.println(f);
       System.out.println("BaseClass time");
    }
}
public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    DerivedClass() {
        super("You did not pass an argument to your object.");
        System.out.println("It's DerivedClass time");
    }
    DerivedClass(String d) {
        System.out.println("Hey look, an argument");
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println("It's DerivedClass time");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DerivedClass defauld = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass custom = new DerivedClass("Ayyyyy");
    }
}
```

What do? I feel like there is no reason this should fail to run. The constructor in DerivedClass which allows you to pass a string is correctly formatted to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that if you don't do it explicitly, when constructing a DerivedClass the compiler will call `super()` with no arguments. The fix is simple:

```
DerivedClass(String d) {
     super(d);
     // rest of your code
}
```

For more information you can read the [Java Language Specification, Section 12.4.2 - Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call the base class constructor (just like you're doing in the other case):

```
DerivedClass(String d) {
    super(d);
    System.out.println("Hey look, an argument");
    ...
```

If you don't do this, the compiler will implicitly try to call the no-args constructor for the base class. There is no such constructor in your code, hence the error message.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about "super".

Answer (score 0):

Java rule: - the first line of the constructor is call to the super class constructor.if you dnt even write this line then the compiler during compilation puts 'super()' which give call to no parameter constructor of super class.

So when program executes the line DerivedClass defauld = new DerivedClass();

The no parameter constructor is executed and the first line is super() which gives call to the no parameter constructor of super class.(which is not present).

Solution: -

Give a no parameter constructor in base class

Or

In your derived class parameterized constructor write super("pass a string"); on first line